# CGRectIntersectsRectで指定する方法

Tags: objective-c

for文でランダムな位置に作成した複数のImageViewが重なった場合、重なったImageViewだけを削除したいのですが、tagをつけたり配列に格納したりしてみましたが、うまく動作しません
どうすればよいかわからないので質問させていただきました。

```
-(void)displayImages
{
    int total = 5;

    for (int i=0; i<total; i++) {
        UIImageView *holeImageView;
        int randOx = 10+arc4random_uniform(240);
        int randOy = 60+arc4random_uniform(430);
        NSInteger tag = i;

        holeImageView = [UIImageView new];
        holeImageView.frame = CGRectMake(randOx,randOy,40,40);
        holeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"startButton.png"];
        [self.view addSubview:holeImageView];
        [holeImageView setTag:tag];
        [ObjectArray addObject:holeImageView];

        if (CGRectIntersectsRect (holeImageView.frame,holeImageView.frame)){
            NSLog(@"%dぶつかりました",i);
            [ObjectArray removeObject:holeImageView];  
        }
    }         
}
```

追記させていただきます

```
       if (CGRectIntersectsRect (ObjectArray[i].frame,holeImageView.frame)){
       if (CGRectIntersectsRect (holeImageView[i].frame,holeImageView.frame)){
```

など他にも思いつくものは試しましたがエラー出ましたので、こちらにどのように記述すれば良いかお聞きしたかったのですが、質問文の書き方が悪く、大変申し訳ないです。

Comment: コメント有り難うございます、ぽぽたん様のおっしゃる通りだとは思いますが。
一部否定させて頂きます、丸投げではございませんこの不具合にかなりの時間と労力を使って試行錯誤した結果、行き詰まってしまったため質問させていただきました。

Comment: ObjectArray[i].frame→((UIView *)ObjectArray[i]).frame　で、いけそうな気がするんですが？つまりObjectiArray[i]だけでは、UIViewのサブクラスと認識してもらえてないのではないかと。

Comment: エラーの種類も書いてないしせめて自分で何が問題なのかを特定してから質問しないと。

Comment: かしこまりました、以後はそちらの方も記述させていただきます。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIViewのプロパティに「subviews」があって、これで「addSubview:」したサブビューの一覧をNSArrayで取得できます。提示のプログラムに即して説明すれば、「**self.view.subviews**」になります。
この配列を使って、総当たりで重なっているかどうかの判定をすればいいでしょう。
（たぶん、subviewsを利用すれば、「ObjectArray」は不用になる気がします。）

どういうジャンルのアプリを開発なさっているのかによりますが、視覚的に派手なものを求めるのなら、UIDynamicBehaviorの活用をお勧めします。

例：[UIKit Dynamicsを使ってみるチュートリアル](http://safx-dev.blogspot.jp/2014/01/uikit-dynamics.html)

このクラスは、Viewに物理的なマスを与えるもので、同じ平面にあるViewは重なり合うことがありません。（リンク先のサンプルでは、Viewが重力で落下しますが、重力をなしに設定することもできます）
ちょっと勉強が必要ですが、勉強の量に比例する、アプリのできばえを期待できます。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます、おかげさまで目的の機能を実装することができました。
UIDynamicBehaviorを使いました。
感謝します。

Answer (score 1):

どう見てもAとBの重なりを判定する関数の引数A,Bに同じものを渡していますが・・・

> if (CGRectIntersectsRect (holeImageView.frame,holeImageView.frame)){

人に聞くより自分でコードをじっくりながめた方が早いですよ。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます、全くその通りだとおもいます、追記しましたのでご確認いただければうれしく思います。